# Github Jekyll theme hacker style does not apply to sublinks

Tags: github, jekyll

I created a GitHub page with a hacker theme.

Then, I created another .md file (other than the index.md) and linked it to the index file.

The referenced .md (named as testlink.md) does not have the same style, unfortunately.

Here is the code: https://github.com/YesimSem/thecuriousanimal/tree/gh-pages

How may I ensure that all the .md files have that same style?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

## Updated Answer

Your link needs to be changed from `.md` to `.html`. Please see this [pull request](https://github.com/YesimSem/thecuriousanimal/pull/1) on your repository for the fix. The `testlink.md` is being rendered correctly but your link is going to the original Markdown file. It should be going to the HTML rendering of the Markdown file. See this URL for the correct page https://yesimsem.github.io/thecuriousanimal/testlink.html

## Original Answer

You need to add [Jekyll Front Matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) to your new page (i.e. `testlink.md`) and specify the a [Jekyll layout](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/layouts/). In your situation, your new page needs the same layout as the `index.md` from the GitHub Jekyll Hacker theme. See the layout specified at the top of [`index.md`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pages-themes/hacker/master/index.md).

Comment: The thing is I used the ready template from github so for the index.md I did not specify any layout, it came like that and then I deleted it, wrote what I want instead and it was working (working == it was the correct layout). I tried writing what is in my yml file before the text for the testlink.md but it did not work, perhaps the issue is that it was a ready template, so it was specified somewhere I do not see.

Comment: @semchena31, my original answer is not applicable to how you build your website using only `_config.yml` to specify the theme. I have found the root cause of your problem and updated this answer.